# Why passed value of datePicker(with Persian date) is default date in MVC?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I try to pass value of datePicker input to the action via model. but always I get this value :

```
Date = {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}
```

I use ajax for serialize  and send value of inputs to the action.
I see console and found that sender value when serialize form is true but value of date in action is wrong.

html :

```
<input id="Fromdate" name="Fromdate" class="input-text full-width hasDatepicker" type="text">
```

Model :

```
 public class CharterFlightSearchModel
    {
        public int Inf { get; set; }
        public int Adt { get; set; }
        public int Chd { get; set; }
        public int depCountryId { get; set; }
        public int DepCityId { get; set; }
        public int ArrCountryId { get; set; }
        public int ArrCityId { get; set; }
        public int DateRange { get; set; }
        public DateTime Fromdate { get; set; }

    }
```

This function called when click on the search button.
jquery :

```
function ShowCharterFlight() {
                $('#WrapCharterFlights').empty();
                $('#WrapCharterFlights').html('<div class="col-xs-12 text-center"><img  class="loadingimg" src="/Content/Travelo/images/travelenter_process.gif" /></div>');
               $.ajax({
                   url: '/Charter/CharterPartialViewResult',
                    data: $("#CharterFlights").serialize(),
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#WrapCharterFlights').html(result);
                        $(".loadingimg").hide();
                        //allow = true;
                    },
                    error: function (jqXhr, textStates, errorThrown) {
                        alert(errorThrown);
                        $(".loadingimg").hide();
                        $('#WrapCharterFlights').html('<div class="text-center"><label class="text-danger btn btn-danger" style="font-size: 16px;">خطا در بارگذاری اطلاعات . لطفا دوباره امتحان کنید. </label></div>');
                        //allow = true;
                    }

                });
            }
```

Comment: What is the actual value of the date, and what is the culture on the server?

Comment: Please add yout HTML or cshtml..

Comment: Actual value : 1395/02/29     , Value of  this date in action : 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

Comment: It would need to be `Fromdate: 1395-02-29` (ISO format)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke  : I test this but don't solved

Comment: `1395-02-29` will bind fine to a `DateTime` property

Comment: I solved it. I use Persian date .In Persian date the number of   days is 30  or 31 days because datetime can not get this date .I test another date such as 1395/3/1 that worked currently. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but if you user the jquery datepicker https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ then the server will correctly parse all dates sent from the client side.

References to the jquery script files:

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="thedatepicker">
```

JQUERY Initialization:

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#thedatepicker" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });

});
```

Your Function (sending the value of the datepicker into the POST request (this datepicker value obviously needs to be validated)

```
function ShowCharterFlight() {
            $('#WrapCharterFlights').empty();
            $('#WrapCharterFlights').html('<div class="col-xs-12 text-center"><img  class="loadingimg" src="/Content/Travelo/images/travelenter_process.gif" /></div>');
           $.ajax({
               url: '/Charter/CharterPartialViewResult',
                data: {date:document.getElementById('startdatepicker').value},
                type: "POST",
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#WrapCharterFlights').html(result);
                    $(".loadingimg").hide();
                    //allow = true;
                },
                error: function (jqXhr, textStates, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                    $(".loadingimg").hide();
                    $('#WrapCharterFlights').html('<div class="text-center"><label class="text-danger btn btn-danger" style="font-size: 16px;">خطا در بارگذاری اطلاعات . لطفا دوباره امتحان کنید. </label></div>');
                    //allow = true;
                }

            });
        }
```